# Laid in/on/at the back seat(car)

Tags: prepositions

Let's say you and your son, who is 3 years old, watched a movie at a theater. Then your son fell asleep and you have to carry him back to your car. And you say:

> I laid my son safely **in/on/at** the back seat of our car.

All of these make sense, but which is correct?

Comment: The three prepositions ***in, on, at*** identify the target reference as a ***container, surface,*** or ***position***. You could lay your child ***at** the back of the car*, since that's a "location", but *the back **seat*** is an "object", not a "place", so you can't reasonably use ***at*** in your context. Actual car seats are usually seen as "surfaces" (that you can sit ***on***) - but you'd be much more likely to use ***in*** if you were using a baby/child car seat, since they have "enclosing" sides. Note that "correct" means "logical, sensible" here, not "grammatical, syntactic"

Comment: Hmm I see, I thought evertime you use ''in'' all the sides should be enclosed completely, like in a box. Thx man, I got it.

Comment: You might find [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28sat+on+the+chair%29%2F%28sat+in+the+chair%29%2C%28sat+on+his+chair%2Fsat+in+his+chair%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28sat%20on%20the%20chair%29%20/%20%28sat%20in%20the%20chair%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28sat%20on%20his%20chair%20/%20sat%20in%20his%20chair%29%3B%2Cc0) interesting. It shows what I would consider a statistically significant difference in the ratios between ***on/in*** in the context of ***his/the chair***...

Comment: In case it's not immediately obvious, although ***in*** is always more common with any kind of ***chair***, this preference is far stronger with ***his** chair* than with ***the** chair*. Reason being that ***his*** chair much more likely to be large, padded, "bucket-like" - a man often has his favourite comfy chair that only he normally sits ***in***, even though he might sit ***on*** any one of 4 identical dining table chairs (which aren't usually of a "containing" design).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I laid my son safely **on** the back seat of our car.

In - would imply you somehow got him to fit inside the seat, under the cushions...

At - not sure what that implies; the seat is at the back of the car, sure, but once you're at the back yourself then that distinction disappears & you then just sit, or lay, **on** the seat.

And, as I was typing this, [FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers) nails the distinction in comments...

> The three prepositions **in, on, at** identify the target reference as a **container, surface, or position**.